# How to take String JSON values into HashMap

Tags: java, json

I have an `org.bson.Document` that I can convert into a `JSON`:

```
for (Document dc : list) {
        String doc = dc.toJson();
    }
```

And the String looks like:

```
{
"_id": "C:\\Users\\santi\\Desktop\\2010-documents.biased\\99\\2010-99-086.html", 

"data": {
        "german": 1, 
        "metadata": 1, 
        "inform": 20, 
        "almanac": 1,
         etc etc
        }
 }
```

I'm stucked at figuring how to access to the `"data"` field and get all the `key-value` values and store them into a HashMap or Map. I thought about spliting the array and getting some substrings etc but doesn't seem like a good way.

Comment: have you tried dc.get("data")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use like this :

```
HashMap<String,Integer> result = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper().readValue(json, HashMap.class);
```

Or

```
Gson GSON = new com.google.gson.Gson();

HashMap<String,Integer> result = GSON.fromJson(json, HashMap.class);
```

Comment: Don't copy and paste the same answer that is already there in the above given link.

Comment: I didn't see that answer this basically very simple question anyone can answer

Comment: @PawanTiwari updated the answer